# Add space between the two icons for all resolutions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I have one static row with two icons **ion-email** and **ion-compose**.

In my demo there is no space between the icons. I need to add some but it must work for all resolutions.

```
<div class="list">

  <a class="item item-icon-right" href="#">
    <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    <i class="icon ion-compose"></i>
    Check mail
  </a>
      </div>
```

I need to add constant space between the two icons.

Here is my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOzOWZ

Comment: have you tried float left and float right respectively?

Answer (score 0):

You need to acheive these changes - [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVEVBj)

```
.item-icon-right i.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: auto;
}
```

This will result in the following css, notice the commented out parts:

```
.item-icon-right .icon {
  /* right: 11px; */
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
.item-icon-left .icon, .item-icon-right .icon {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 0; */
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution would be to statically position the first icon.

Simply add this class to your CSS.

```
.item-icon-right i:nth-child(1) {
  right: 50px;
}
```

For a more robust solution, I would suggesting creating styles for a separate component that can be floated to the right and will contain inline icons.

```
.icon-holder-right {
  float: right;
}
```

For example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwYwqw

The benefit of this approach is that you won't overwrite any existing rules, meaning it's not likely to break any other parts of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.icon{
  position:inherit !important;
  display:inline-block !important;
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: This will change the styles of every icon. You probably don't want them all to be floating right.